# how to pass magic mocked references to main method in python

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I've tried to stub out classes constructed in the main function so that I can test against main and assert that classes are initialized with specific data. However main function still does not pick up the mocked instances. How can I pass along the mocked instance to main.

```
from unittest.mock import patch
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def use_mocked(method, cls, ret_value):

class MockedClass(cls):
    pass

def func(cls):
    return ret_value

def fullname(o):
    return o.__module__ + "." + o.__name__

setattr(MockedClass, method, classmethod(func))

with patch(fullname(cls), MockedClass):
    yield
```

This is the patching utility to make sure main is passed the mocked reference. I may be confused on my understanding of how its functioning.

```
def test_main():
    magic_b = MagicMock(spec_set=Benchmark, wraps=Benchmark)
    with use_mocked("__new__", DataStream, magic_b):
        main.main()
        magic_b.assert_called_once_with() # fails
```

in the main module, I have a main method defined as...

```
import benchmark.Benchmark
def main():
    b = benchmark.Benchmark() # <- this is not the mocked instance
    ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I relied on the same patch utility in unittest.mock but instead just used it in the form of a decorator around my test. `patch()` now is passed in the Benchmark class which main imports (it is important to patch in main and not in benchmark modules it self **ie. don't patch benchmark.Benchmark**). Main module remains untouched and tests now pass.

```
import main

@patch("main.Benchmark")
# b here is a ref to MagicMock class mocking Benchmark;
# it is substituted into the execution of main module,
# patch provides it as a param so you can assert against it.
def test_main(b): 
    main.main()
    b.assert_called_once_with()
```